# Matlab: Difference bettween two different sized arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, array-difference

Is it possible to find the difference beetwen two arrays of different size?

My problem is that I have two arrays, that scaled are pretty similar and I need the error in each point.

The data look like this:-

[image]

Yaw data is much bigger than Yaw Ref.

Comment: it's perfectly possible- create a padded array (use size property for the largest of your two arrays), populate the padded array with smaller array, and then compare.

Comment: the padarray function only allows adding values at the end or the beginning or both sides of the array, but I don't wat that. I need to make correspond the end and the star or both arrays, and fill in some elements of one because is too small.

Comment: I think with this image of both arrays without scaling them is necessary to understand [data2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B20R_Z0cMZiZLTBHWUtjWUZlUFU)

Comment: I think what you need is sampling some intermediate points for the Yaw Ref. The number of new intermediate samples can be determined by the difference in the length of the two data sets. And the sample values can be computed by interpolating neighboring data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a very naive approach and simply pad each element of the reference array. That is fairly simple to do:

```
n = length(yaw)/length(yaw_ref);

yaw_ref_pad = zeros(length(yaw), 1);
for j = 1:length(yaw_ref)-1
    yaw_ref_pad((n*j):(n*(j+1)) = yaw_ref(j);
end
```

You could also do something more adaptive, which may or may not be what you want. This approach uses the derivatives to determine where the padded reference should switch. This might be considered a bit circular, since your system looks like an overdamped PID system and this uses the output to seed the input.

```
yaw_ref_pad = zeros(length(yaw), 1);
[x, peaks] = findpeaks(diff(yaw));
for j = 1:length(peaks)-1
    yaw_ref_pad(peaks(j):peaks(j+1)) = yaw_ref(j);
end
```

Either way, after filling `yaw_ref_pad`, your result is simply

```
error = yaw_ref_pad - yaw;
```

Comment: Thank oyu very much, the first method worked perfectly fine and it was exactly what I was looking for!